# can you convert a dict() to a sequence?

Tags: csv, dictionary, python-3.4

I have a dict() for all the nmea sentences that are found in a csv. I tried creating another csv to write the results of the dict() into it for statistical and logging purposes. However, I can't due to the dict() not being 'callable'?

```
import csv

#Counts the number of times a GPS command is observed
def list_gps_commands(data):
    """Counts the number of times a GPS command is observed.

Returns a dictionary object."""

    gps_cmds = dict()
    for row in data:
        try:
            gps_cmds[row[0]] += 1 
        except KeyError:
            gps_cmds[row[0]] = 1

    return gps_cmds

print(list_gps_commands(read_it))
print ("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")


with open('gpsresults.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
  spamwriter.writerow(list_gps_commands(read_it))
```

Can someone help me? Is there a way I can convert the keys/values into sequences so the csv module can recognize it? Or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `csv.DictWriter` instead of `csv.writer`.

Comment: I'm away from my computer where I have my work on...will the 'csv.DictWriter' allow csv to write the whole  dictionary expression?

Comment: It will write any fields you specify in the `DictWriter` constructor's `fieldnames` argument, no more, no less.

Comment: I will it look like in csv if you get a result when you print it like this {rmc:3, gga:5, gll:2} ?

Comment: If you specified `fieldnames=['gga', 'rmc']`, then `.writerow(rowdict)` will print `5,3`. `.writeheader()` will write the fieldnames themselves.

Comment: so could I then call specifically to spamwriter.writerow(list_gps_commands(read_it).keys()) and  spamwriter.writerow(list_gps_commands(read_it).values())

Comment: You don't want to call `.values()` (or `.keys()`) - they will reduce the dict to a list, but with no guaranteed order, so you'll be getting rubbish CSV. `DictWriter` docs have a nice example, follow that and you'll be fine.